# How do you configure a DataSource in Java to connect to MS SQL Server?

Tags: java, sql-server, datasource

I'm trying to follow Java's JDBC tutorials to write a Java program that can connect to SQL Server 2008.  I'm getting lost at the point of making a connection.

The following snippet is from the tutorial:

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/myDB");
Connection con = ds.getConnection();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource()
ds.setPort(1527);
ds.setHost("localhost");
ds.setUser("APP")
ds.setPassword("APP");
Connection con = ds.getConnection();
```

There's no explanation of what comp/env/jdbc/myDB should point to, and I don't know how I should choose a port.  Also, the object ds seems to be defined twice.

I'm using the `JSQLDataSource` driver, for the record.  Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

Comment: These answers are somewhat helpful.  I'll accept an answer if someone can explain why ds is defined twice in Sun's tutorial.

Comment: I'm just going through the same process!  I was looking at this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html which starts talking about coffee shops!  At that point I gave up.  You've got to love java/oracle documentation!

Comment: Actually, it has improved a bit in the last five years. It has significantly fewer errors, from the last time I checked. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start with the [JDBC tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) or the [Microsoft docs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313100).

and this:

```
String driver = "com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver";
Class.forName(driver);
String url = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://host:1433/database";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");
```

Fill in your values for host, database, username, and password.  The default port for SQL server is 1433.

UPDATE: Good point below.  JDBC drivers can be had from both Microsoft and jTDS.  I prefer the latter.

JNDI lookups have to do with Java EE app servers that support connection pooling.  You can ask the app server to create a pool of connections, which can be an expensive thing to do, and loan them out to clients like library books as needed.

If you aren't using a Java EE app server or connection pooling, you have to create the connection on your own.  That's where manual processes and DriverManager come in.

EXPLANATION: As for why the Sun tutorial shows DataSource twice, I'd say it's a case of poor editing.  If you look above the code sample it says you can get a DataSource "by lookup or manually".  The code snippet below shows both together, when it should be one or the other.

You know it's an inadvertent error because there's no way the code as written could compile.  You have "ds" declared twice.

So it should read "...lookup", followed by its code snippet, and then "...manually", followed by its code snippet.

Comment: Alright, I'm hung up on something really simple.  What might the "host" be?  Is that a path to the MSSQL program?

Comment: "host" is either the name or the IP address of the server on which SQL Server is running (e.g. "localhost" or "127.0.0.1".

Comment: any idea how to use data sources instead of the drivermanager?  From reading the [introductory documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html) it seems this is the recommended way.  I've also seen people saying you don't need to use Class.forname anymore either.  Dont know what the motivation for that is though

Comment: The introductory documentation usually assumes that you don't have a Java EE app server, because writing your own Java classes is certainly simpler.  Not needing Class.forName() is a newer feature in the JDK (7 and newer, I believe).  The "motivation" is a change in the JDK.

Comment: Just to add: jTds, although was a good choice, is not being maintained anymore, no updates since 2013 and is not JDBC 4.0 compatible. Some projects already switched to MS driver

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure anyone above has really answered the question.

I found [this microsoft sample useful](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342342.aspx).

The key information in there is really that the class you need is **SQLServerDataSource**
that is basically a configuration object - you use it something like this:

```
    SQLServerDataSource dataSource = new SQLServerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUser("aUser");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");
    dataSource.setServerName("hostname");
    dataSource.setDatabaseName("db");
```

You would then call

```
dataSource.getConnection();
```

to get a connection object which is basically the thing you use to talk to the database.

Use

```
connection.prepareStatement("some sql with ? substitutions");
```

to make something for firing off sql and:

```
connection.prepareCall
```

for calling stored procedures.

Answer (score 4):

I like the [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/index.html) driver for connecting to SQL Server.  
A URL will look like this:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/Finance;instance=sqlexpress
```

Check [this](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat) for jTDS Url Info.

[This](http://softwaresalariman.blogspot.com/2007/04/jdbc-to-sql-server-express.html) also has some interesting information to help troubleshoot jtds to sql express sorts of problems.

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered long time ago. The question was asked about JNDI lookup. With lookup you have to see the application server log to see what the connection is bound to. For example in Jboss startup, I can see:

```
[ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=myDB' to JNDI name 'java:myDB'
```

Using that name=myDB you lookup

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = ic.lookup("java:myDB");
```

Notice how the server log and the code both point to the JNDI name **java:myDB**.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataSource ds = new SimpleDriverDataSource(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver(),
    "jdbc:mysql://database:1433;databaseName=name", "username", "password");
JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
```